# How to use webhooks with shopify_app gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

for the last hours I've been trying to add a webhook to my Shopify app using the official shopify_app gem.

So I ran `rails g shopify_app:add_webhook -t products/update -a https://example.com/webhooks/products_update` and saw every file getting generated as expected and checking the logs after installing my app in a Test Store also showed me that the webhook was initiated successfully.

However, after actually updating a product in the shop, I get an error saying:

```
ShopifyApp::MissingWebhookJobError (ShopifyApp::MissingWebhookJobError):

shopify_app (7.2.9) app/controllers/shopify_app/webhooks_controller.rb:21:in `webhook_job_klass'
shopify_app (7.2.9) app/controllers/shopify_app/webhooks_controller.rb:10:in `receive'
actionpack (5.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
```

...going on for about 40 lines more and repeating itself after about 10-30 seconds, however, showing me the params before throwing it. I haven't changed the `products_job.rb`, so it's still looking like this: (although I've tried to change it many times)

```
class ProductsJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(shop_domain:, webhook:)
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)

    shop.with_shopify_session do
    end
  end
end
```

I'd be really happy to get any input on this, as I'm new to Shopify Apps and to Rails too (as you can probably tell ^^)

Thanks, Georg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your products update job file name should be like products_update_job.rb not products_job.rb also the contents should be as below:

```
class ProductsUpdateJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(shop_domain:, webhook:)
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)

    shop.with_shopify_session do
    end
  end
end
```

Try this changes you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your rails server after installing the webhook.
Do restart your rails server also uninstall and reinstall your app in the shopify store and before clicking install button check your corresponding webhook is available there or not in the installation page.

Comment: I have tried restarting the server and reinstalling the app in the Shopify store several times, unfortunately that didn't help.. What do you mean with "check your corresponding webhook is available there or not in the installation page"? Before clicking install, I can only see which permissions my app is requesting, nothing about any webhooks...